# How to use NSArray and NSDictionary?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I'm learning **iOS** from **iTunes U** and trying to build a programmable calculator. I have added three variables which the user can use to allot values. I understand that the variables would be passed as `NSString` objects and then the user would touch the numbers which would be passed as `NSNumbers` and allotted to the variables. I don't understand how to use `NSArrays` and `NSDictionary` to allot the numbers to these variables. Sorry for being a complete newbie, but I am not comfortable with the Documentation right now, so it is kind of fuzzy! This is my code for appending digits on a `UILabel` and then using it for calculations:

```
- (IBAction)digitPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
  NSString *digit = [sender currentTitle];
  if (self.userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber) {
    self.display.text = [self.display.text stringByAppendingFormat:digit];
    everythingBrainLabel.text = [self.everythingBrainLabel.text stringByAppendingFormat:digit];
  } else {
    self.display.text = digit;
    self.everythingBrainLabel.text = [self.everythingBrainLabel.text stringByAppendingFormat:@" %@", digit];
    self.userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber = YES;
  }  
}
```

I can get the values of the variables in an `NSMutableArray` but how to allot numbers here by simply pressing the digits after pressing the variable? I added `NSLog` just to check if variables were being passed and they show up in the console after I press the respective variable.

```
- (IBAction)variablePressed:(UIButton *)sender {
  NSString *variablePressed = [sender currentTitle];
  NSMutableArray *variableValues = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:variablePressed, nil];
  for(int i = 0; i < [variableValues count]; i++) {
    NSLog(@"%@",[variableValues objectAtIndex:i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: please be more specific about your question

Comment: I just want to allot numbers to the variables to make this a programmable calculator, like if the user wants to allot 3 to variable "x" and then use x as 3 again and again in the calculation. How should I do that? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set specific value for specific keys, you could add an NSMutableDictionary to your current class
Add it as a property in your class and synthesize it
Now when you want to assign a value for "x" you would do the following

```
//Add this var in your .h file create a property around it
NSMutableDictionary *variables;
//in the .m @synthesize variables;
```

When assigning the variable "x"

```
//for example you want to set varialbe "x" = 20
int xValue = 20;
NSString *xVariable = @"x";
[variables setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:xValue] forKey:xVariable];
```

Getting value for "x"

```
//Later on if you want to get x
NSString *xVariable = @"x";
int xValue = [[variables valueForKey:xVariable] intValue];
```